# What is the proof of $n^2 = 1 + 3 + 5 ... (2*n - 1)$

Tags: proof-writing

What is the proof of $n^2 = 1 + 3 + 5 + ... + (2\times n - 1)$?

While I verified that this is true for small numbers, I am looking for a mathematical proof for all Natural Numbers .

Comment: observe that $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + (2n +1)$ and use mathematical induction

Comment: Are you familiar with induction?

Comment: Are you looking for a formal proof? If so, look at mathematical induction. Or are you looking for an "at sight" proof, that uses a diagram to make it look obvious? If so, cut up a square with side $n$ into pieces of size $1$, $3$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction, it is true for $n=1$, this is immediate. Suppose it is true for $n$, then let us calculate $(n+1)^2$ using the hypothesis of induction

$$(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1=1+3+\cdots +(2n-1)+(2n+1)=1+3+\cdots +(2n-1)+(2(n+1)-1)$$
And the formula is true for $n+1$ we are done!

Answer (score 4):

A different approach $$S=1+3+\cdots+2n-1$$ $$S=2n-1+2n-3+\cdots +1$$ adding both of them yields $$2S=2n+2n+\cdots+2n$$ implying $$2S=(2n)\cdot n $$ thus $$S=n^2$$

Answer (score 2):

To supplement the answers already given, there is also a geometric proof of this result.

For example:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ [image]

$$ 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 = 5^2 $$

Answer (score 0):

Using the summation [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Derivation) of Arithmetic Series  $$\sum_{r=1}^n(2r-1)=\frac n2(1+2n-1)$$

---

Alternatively,  $$2r-1=r^2-(r-1)^2$$

Now set $r=1,2,\cdots,n-1,n$ and add

**See also**: [Telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the formula for the sum of *all* the positive integers between $\;1\;$ and $\;n\;$ you can do as follows:

$$1+3+5+\ldots+(2n-1)=1+2+3+4+\ldots+(2n-1)+2n-(2+4+\ldots+2n)=$$

$$=\frac{2n(2n+1)}2-2(1+2+\ldots+n)=n(2n+1)-n(n+1)=n^2$$

Answer (score 0):

$1+3+5+\cdots+(2n-1)=\frac{(1+2n-1)\times n}{2}=n^2$

Comment: Please consider elaborating on this answer to make it more useful to the author of the question.